# Open-source navigation software and 3rd party hardware

Tags: open-source, navigation

I'm a bit fed up with the current navigator (TomTom) as it turned to adware after six months of use. "Please buy new maps at www.tomtom.com, click this button to see what you wanted to do".

Is there any (good) OSS navigation software with support for proprietary hardware? I'm perfectly happy to purchase separate maps and hardware for the software as long as I don't have to give my money to TomTom or Navigon.

Comment: The current proprietary software is so far away what good software is.  For example, # Show how many minutes till turn   # Log route time history and use this in calculations   # Accept it if driver overrides the route for twenty times. The route is better.   # Find and route gas stations closest to the route.

Comment: # community updates on road changes based on path travelled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check [Routing using Open Street Map](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing).

Comment: That's a good link. So much software already developed based on openstreetmap. Handheld support seems to be based on mainly mobile phones. It would be great to have some hardware vendor interested and maybe use B2G based OS.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not OSS, Waze is a crowdsourced navigation app that does some of the things you mentioned. It allows users to post improved routes when the navigation algorithm doesn't find the best route. I have not used the app, so I don't know if it has the other improvements on usability that you mentioned in your first comment. They are a new app, so maybe would be more responsive to UI suggestions than TomTom or Navigon.

Comment: uh sorry, I think you have me confused with someone else. I'm not affiliated with Waze in any way.